# Quando usar Html.BeginForm() e porque usar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Me deparei com a seguinte situação, em uma das `views` tenho um campo de busca:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">            
        @Html.TextBox("parametroProcura")
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

Lendo, e vendo alguns videos na internet, percebi que o pessoal coloca o campo de busca dentro de um `@Html.BeginForm`:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">              
            @Html.TextBox("parametroProcura")
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
}
```

Porem, a busca funciona nos dois casos, então... porque usar `@Html.BeginForm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O ASP.NET MVC framework possui *helpers* que fornecem uma maneira fácil de renderizar HTML nas *Views*, entre eles o `Html.BeginForm()`.

Usando `@using (Html.BeginForm()){ ... }`, automaticamente é adicionada a tag `<form>` na sua página. Esse *helper* possui sobrecargas onde você informa a Action, Controller entre outros parâmetros, veja maiores detalhes [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460542(v=vs.118).aspx).

Obs.: Quando você utiliza esse helper usando `using`, você não precisa se preocupar com a tag `</form>` de fechamento pois esse *helper* já cuida disso para você.

> Por que usar?

Ela é como  uma *[syntactic sugar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A7%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1tico)* para `<form method="post" action="@Url.Action(...)">...</form>` então, você usa o que tiver preferência, trabalhando com *Razor* nas *Views*, você pode escolher fazer na mão ou usar os *helpers*.

**Edição**

> Perfeito, uma ultima duvida, posso usar quantos @Html.BeginForm() por view? ou é ilimitado?

Você pode utilizar mais de um `@Html.BeginForm()` na página.
Exemplo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaActionX", "SeuControllerX", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ...
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaActionY", "SeuControllerY", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ...
}
```

Será então renderizado algo como:

```
<form action="/SeuControllerX/SuaActionX" method="post">
    ...
</form>

<form action="/SeuControllerY/SuaActionY" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Adicionando: Ele previne erros de digitação, validação em tempo de desenvolvimento,e também referencia seus *target endpoints* por tipos. Assim, se vc mudar o `Route` de uma `Action Controller`, todos os `Forms` que façam referencia à ela irão renderizar para a nova rota, sem esforço adicional.

Comment: Perfeito, uma ultima duvida, posso usar quantos `@Html.BeginForm()` por view? ou é ilimitado?