# Problema ao executar método para inserir novo Usuario usando ASP.NET MVC com HTML e RAZOR

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, front-end

Estou com um problema na hora de executar uma request para efetuar a inserção de uma novo usuário, não sei o que preciso fazer agora pra finalizar minha requisição, **Ao clicar no botão de cadastrar não acontece nada**
abaixo estão meu código HTML e o controlador (Nome do Controller: UsuarioController)

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Nome", placeholder = "Nome", required = "required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <!--                    Confirmação de password                      -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) <br>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Email", type = "Email", placeholder = "Email", required = "required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "help-block with-errors" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) <br>
        <div class="form-inline row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "inputPassword", placeholder = "Password", required = "required", minlenght = "6", type = "password" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "help-block with-errors" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Opa, as senhas não batem" placeholder="Confirm" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
        }
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-login">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

<>
    // GET: Usuario
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", Repo.Listar());
    }

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adicionar(Usuario user)
{
    Repo.Adicionar(user);
    return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Atualizar(Usuario user)
{
    Repo.Atualizar(user);
    return View("~\\Views\\Principal\\Principal.cshtml");//?
}

// DELETE : Usuario
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Repo.Deletar(id);
    return View("Index", Repo.Listar());
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara, tente editar. Ao editar sugiro que você descreva mais detalhes do problema/erro que está ocorrendo. Analisando o código percebo algumas coisas estranhas, mas não da para inferir uma resposta sem saber exatamente o problema.

Comment: Você não informou qual é o problema que está tendo... informe o problema.. e ao olhar o seu `Controller` você definiu dois métodos com o mesmo nome  `AddUsuario`, sem especificar qual receberá requisições do tipo `POST`tente colocar o `DataAnotation``HttpPost` no método que recebe a `ViewModel`como parâmetro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *[helper Html.BeginForm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220293/quando-usar-html-beginform-e-porque-usar/220311#220311)* que marca o início de um formulário não contempla seus campos.

Analisando seu código é como se no seu formulário houvesse apenas um botão:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
        }
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-login">Login</button>
</div>
```

Ajuste o seu código incluindo no formulário (dentro do *helper Html.BeginForm*) todos os campos e como na sua controller você define `[HttpPost]` na action Adicionar, altere também o parâmetro de FormMethod.Get para `FormMethod.Post`:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post))
        {

        <!-- INSIRA O CÓDIGO DO FORMULÁRIO AQUI -->

            <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
        }
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-login">Login</button>
</div>
...
```

Exemplo:

Model:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public String Email { get; set; }

    public String Senha { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplicationMVC.Models.Usuario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar";
}

<h2>Adicionar</h2>

@*A linha de baixo ou @using (Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Usuario", FormMethod.Post))*@
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Usuario</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Adicionar()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Adicionar(Usuario user)
    {
        Repo.Adicionar(user);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Debugando valores enviados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ainda não está enviando a requisição mas talvez eu saiba o motivo... eu preciso do Html.Submit button ao invés do html não é?

Comment: Editei a resposta e criei um exemplo completo para você. Com base nele faça testes e ajuste.