# Botão em uma View com MVC/Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Quando colocamos um botão em uma View, como fazemos para disparar um click dele?
Tenho esse botão:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarregaDados.Models.Cliente>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Criar Usuário", "AdicionaUsuario")
</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Teste" onclick=""/>
```

E tenho esse controller

```
public class IndexController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Enviar()
        {
            string uri = "http://www.meu_site.com.br/autorizador/api/getliberaitens/value";

            return null;
        }
        public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "text/plain";
            request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Como eu faço, pelo botão, disparar qualquer método ou Action na controller?

Comment: Uma aplicação web não tem estado. Portanto, não se "dispara" eventos/métodos nos _controllers_. É preciso fazer com que o seu método atenda alguma requisição HTTP e fazer com que o botão envie esta requisição.

Comment: O que você pretende que o botão faça? Chame uma view ou envie dados para o servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa fazer um Post, uma opção é usar o [helper Html.BeginForm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220293/quando-usar-html-beginform-e-porque-usar/220311#220311) para criar um formulário, ajuste o seu código incluindo o seu código HTML no formulário (dentro do helper Html.BeginForm) e na sua controller defina o atributo *[HttpPost]* na action, exemplo:

View:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SuaAction", "SeuController", FormMethod.Post))
        {

        <!-- INSIRA O CÓDIGO HTML DO FORMULÁRIO AQUI -->           
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Teste"/>

        }
</div>
...
```

Controller:

```
public class SeuController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SuaAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: @pnet A resposta foi útil?